# How can I place a "PLAY GAME" Button on our game's community page?

Tags: facebook

I saw that Zombie Island has changed over to the new timeline format and has a great play game button at the top near the messages button. I've poured through the new info and tutorials and can't find the information on how to get this button for our community page.

Answer (score 1):

[According to this Q/A](http://www.scirra.com/forum/new-facebook-changes-and-how-it-affects-c2_topic50007.html), You must set up your app profile information correctly and completely.

```
Setting
-> Basics
--> Application domain: Enter here the domain you have uploaded your game to
--> Facebook Integration
---> Website: You need to insert a website, even if it does not exist at all
---> Application on Facebook: Secure Canvas-URL (Enter here the path to your game, starting with https://)
```